# Ajax call not working on iPhones when opened from Skype

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, skype, cfc

When I open a page URL from a Skype message, the simple jQuery Ajax call on that page is not working on iPhones. There is no error, but the Ajax call is not fired at all. The same Ajax call works fine when the page is opened directly in the Safari browser on the iPhone. Can somebody help me understand why this is specifically happening with the links shared on Skype? Below is the Ajax code I am calling:

```
function createContract(){
    var myname = document.getElementById('legalname').value;

    $.ajax({
        url:"upload_functions.cfc",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            method:"updateInfo",
            signername:myname
            },
        success: function(data) {
            ShowDialogBox('Thank you','Information updated successfully', 'OK');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This question needs more context. Also, are you wrapping the Ajax call in $(document).ready(function() {...}); ? Do you have global JavaScript error handling setup? Maybe there’s a js error that happens before this is called, in which case js will stop executing.

Comment: I have not wrapped the Ajax call inside $(document).ready(function() {...}); This is wrapped inside a javascript function which is called on click of a button on that page. (I have edited the code above) In my scenario, on iPhones, if you open the page URL from Skype, nothing happens on click of the button, whereas it should show an alert box. I don't know how to check for the browser console on iPhones.

Comment: Using jQuery, it’s standard to use $(document).ready() to start your DOM manipulations. You should be assigning your click handlers inside your ready function. How are you assigning your click function?

Comment: $(document).ready() This was helpful. Thank you @Redtopia